# How does shell pipe the child process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, linux-kernel

Recently I'm studying linux inter process communication. But I have some problems in understanding the pipe mechanism.

I know that pipe is a pair of files created by parent process, then the parent process passes the file descriptors to its child process then child process can operate on it.

But since child process has a totally new virtual memory when exec() is called after fork(), so why can the parent process pass its information to the child process? Is there anything that I have missed?

Comment: File descriptors point to a common file data structure in the kernel, so the kernel can expose the same file to multiple processes.

Comment: Check out www.aosabook.org (bash) and Jessi Storimer (http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766107-a-unix-shell-in-ruby). Do not know if this will answer your questions, but give you insights.

Answer (score 2):

A file descriptor is a handle to a resource managed by the operating system(kernel). When you create a pipe, the kernel creates facilities so data can be sent from one end of the pipe to the other.

This data is sent via the kernel.

When you fork(), the child inherits all file descriptors, which means they inherit the data structure that is managed by the kernel that the file descriptors refer to.
So now the file descriptor refers to the very same kernel resource in the child and the parent. Since the kernel resource lives in the kernel, that part is shared between the 2 processes, it is not duplicated like the user space memory.

Basically, you write() data to one end of the pipe, that data is copied into a buffer in the kernel. You can then read() that data, and it gets copied from the kernel buffer into memory space of the reading process. After a fork(), both child and parent refer to that same buffer in the kernel which was created with pipe().

Comment: That resource managed by the kernel is called _file description_. From [open](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/open.html): _The open() function shall establish the connection between a file and a __file descriptor__. It shall create an open __file description__ that refers to a file and a __file descriptor__ that refers to that open __file description__. The file descriptor is used by other I/O functions to refer to that file._

Answer (score 2):

When a process exec()s to another, that child generally inherits the parent's standard file paths: stdin(0), stdout(1), stderr(2). When a shell creates a pipeline, it uses the `dup2()` call to duplicate a path to a desired path number in order to force the right paths to the child's standard paths.

```
// pseudo-code:
// create the pipe
int pipe_end[2];
pipe(pipe_end);

// "back up" stdin
int save_in = dup(0);

// position the pipe to stdin for the benefit of the child
dup2(pipe_end[0], 0);

// start the child
fork() && exec();

// restore stdin
close(0);
dup2(save_in, 0);

// write to the child
write(pipe_end[1], ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The information isn't passed to the child process - it's done by an implicit convention. The parent knows it should dup2 the fds into slots 0,1,2, and the child knows to read/write from those descriptors. You're right that there's no magic involved across the exec, the child really does get zero information from its parent, aside from the argument and environment vectors. It's just that the unix platform has these conventions, so the child knows the relevant fds it's looking to use, and the parent knows which numbers to pick for the fds.

For processes where you need to pass more than two or three fds, the parent does indeed have to explicitly pass the number. Here are some processes on my machine where this is clearly happening (it's probably stuffed in an environment variable in other places):

- `klauncher --fd=8`
- `/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session`